# Jarsigner "Please specify alias name" ... but I did?

Tags: java, code-signing, jar-signing

I'm a bit baffled as to why I can't sign an applet.

```
d:\project> keytool.exe -importcert -alias mykey -file mycert.cer
[...]
Trust this certificate? [no]:  yes
Certificate was added to keystore

d:\project> jarsigner.exe -signedjar myjar.jar mykey
Please specify alias name
```

According to the syntax given by `jarsigner --help` I have given an alias of `mykey`.  What is going wrong?

Comment: `mykey` is the jar file. not the alias. See first example (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the *Examples* section at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html:

When you use the `-signedjar` option, `jarsigner` expects two jar file names, the original name and the destination name. So the correct syntax would be

```
jarsigner.exe -signedjar signedMyJar.jar myjar.jar mykey
```

If you want to overwrite the jar file, use

```
jarsigner.exe myjar.jar mykey
```

In your case, `jarsigner` interprets `mykey` as the original jar file and expects another argument which is not there.